# How do I calculate PayPal's fees (2.9% + .30) on a fixed number?

Tags: php, javascript, function, math

Sounds like an easy question, I know. I am literally stumped.

Here are two websites that have made the simple calculator:

http://thefeecalculator.com

http://ppcalc.com

I'm needing to calculate these PayPal's fees in my PHP application.

Here's what I got, say we wanted to be paid $30 "even" for membership fees. This is the function I'm using to calculate what we should charge to make up for it using PayPal's calculations (also described on both of the sites above): 2.9% of the transaction + $0.30.

```
function memfees()
{
    $calc = round((30 * .029) + 30 + .30,2);
    return $calc;
}
```

Test it here: http://matt.mw/junk/php/memfees.php
As you can see, it says 31.17.
Both of the other websites say it should be 31.20.
If I try $130.00, mine calculates to $134.07 and both of theirs calculate to $134.19.

What am I doing wrong?

Why am I using a Round function? Percentages cause some decimals to go past the hundredths place, and PayPal generates an error if there is more then 2 digits after the decimal. I thought people normally round money, (e.g. $31.6342 will be $31.63) but if that is the case, what am I doing wrong in my function? The amount that is off is further if there are large payments. This leads me to believe that something is wrong with the percentage portion.

Could you offer some help on this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Because 2.9% of 31.20 + .30 = 1.20; when you raise the amount, more money goes to PayPal :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your function does seem strange. To break it down, PayPal is charging a fixed rate of $.30, and adding a transaction percentage fee of 2.9%.

The formula for this is to add the $.30 and then divide by the percentage difference (100% - 2.9%), which will give you the amount prior to the actual reduction by PayPal.

```
function memfees($amount)
{
    $amount += .30;
    return $amount / (1 - .029);
}
```

You can round and float that as you wish.

Comment: `PayPal is charging a fixed rate of $.30, and adding a transaction percentage fee of 2.9%.` Where did you find that? It seems correct but i want a proof ;)

Comment: This must be how it is calculated. The other answer was onto it but still had a lot of question. I was able to replicate the calculators by putting a round function around all of this. Thank you, Jordan!

Comment: To clarify: The difference is that Paypal uses the *final* amount to calculate the 2.9%, not the $30. So fees = X*0.029 + 0.3, and you get Y = X - fees. So Y = X-(X*1.029+0.3) = X(1-0.029)-0.3, so X = (Y + 0.3)/(1-0.029), given above.

Comment: @meze it's on their website. Pretty standard. Not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: @Jordan on their website i see `2.9% + $0.3 fee` which doesn't tell me that %2.9 applies to $0.3...

Comment: I see what you mean. It could be the other way around, for sure. In which case $amount += .30 would go after the division.

Comment: I'm still not understanding Phil H's explanation; maybe there are a few errors in it. Could someone please clarify?

Comment: @Sam It's just algebra. Y = (the amount you want to receive after fees) and X = (the amount you need to charge to receive Y).  Phil incorrectly substituted 1.029 instead of 0.029 in one of the steps is all, and corrected it in the next step.

Comment: @mootinator Right, I assumed that was an error, and that's why I found his comment confusing. Does my answer below describe the math clearly?

Answer (score 7):

Because you're thinking about it the wrong way around.

You don't charge $30, you charge $31.20. Paypal takes the transaction fee (2.9%) off of *that* and then takes $0.30 from the result:

```
  $31.20
*  0.971 (1 - 2.9%)
  ------
  $30.2952
- $00.30
  ------
  $29.9952
```

So you have to reverse this process, i.e. add $0.3 to your total and divide by 0.971.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure whether the fixed transaction fee gets subtracted before or after the percentage. This could account for a tiny difference ($0.0089) in the final result

Comment: Can you give a link to the paypal where you found that it takes the transaction fee first and then calculates 2.9% ?

Comment: Paypal says 2.9% + $0.30 per transaction. So the percentage first.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. As I say the difference is less than a cent but I've edited the calculation

Comment: So if we want to get 30.5, then we shall charge 31.71 (30.5/.0971 + 0.3). Now we use ppcal.com and set person sends 31.71, and we get $30.49. Something is wrong again ;s

Comment: I cannot understand how to make this into a function because you cannot just "start" with the calculated amount. Let me keep thinking about this, I'd appreciate any help as well.

Comment: Interestingly, the formula I originally used works in this case, and the correction made by @meze causes it to fail

Comment: Looks like we were both wrong. It takes 2.9% of $0.30 fee too. Then math becomes correct: ((30.5 + 0.3) / 0.971) = 31.72

Comment: Your original formula doesn't work either: 30.5 / .971 + 0.3 = 31,71091658084449

Answer (score 7):

Here's a good mathematical explanation of how this works. We have this number, x, which we want to charge a credit card. We don't know what this number is, but we know that when we subtract 30 cents and subtract 2.9% of x, we get y, which is the amount of money we take home:

```
y = x - x * .029 - .3
```

We know y, because we know what amount we want to take home. Say, we wanted to take home $100, then y = 100. But what's x?

```
y = x - x * .029 - .3
y + .3 = x - x * .029
         = x(1 - .029)
(y + .3) / (1 - .029) = x
x = (y + .3) / .971
```

*Note: because `x - x * .029` can be written as `x * 1 - x * .029` then all need to do is just use distributive property and we come up with `x(1 - .029)`*

So we come up with the formula:

```
x = (y + .3) / .971
```

Which defines this infamous number, x. Also, it answers our question; What amount should I charge a card in order to cover the transaction fee and not fall short of the amount we want to take home? Well, all we need to do is fill in the take home amount, which is y:

```
x = (100 + .3) / .971
x = ~103.30
```

I hope this helps clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In C#

```
public decimal CalcFee()
{
    //PayPal Percentage Fee = 0.29%, Fix Fee = 0.3
    var sum = this.Items.Sum(c => c.Price * c.Qty); //Total Items
    return Math.Round(Math.Round((sum + (decimal)0.3) / (decimal)0.971, 2) - sum, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A math problem. 100 % is not what you think:

- 100 % + the fixed fee needs to be charged
- 100 % is actualy `97,1 % payout ($ 30) + 2,9 % fee`
- To get 100 %, we apply the rule of three

e.g.:

```
 97.10 % = $ 30
  1.00 % = $ 30 / 97.1
100.00 % = $ 30 / 97.1 * 100
============================
100.00 % ~ 30,90
```

Now we need to add the fixed fee:

```
$ 30,90 +  $ 0.30
```

Which is resulting in the requested `$ 31.20`

So what does this mean in Code?

```
//untested, not a php developer anymore
function requiredChargement($requiredPrice)
{
    $requiredPercentage = 100.0 - 2.9;
    $fullVariableCost = $requiredPrice / requiredPercentage * 100.0;
    return round($fullVariableCost + 0.3, 2);
}
```